# What's the quickest way to play with GWT for someone with almost no spare time?

Tags: java, gwt, frameworks

I think the subject pretty much covers it.  I'm not a web programmer (I am a programmer), I'd like to write some play web apps, I don't really have a lot of spare time.  So what's the quickest way to get up and running to play around with GWT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say Google's [GWT Quick Start](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html). That said, learning some Java skills would be a good idea if you're not already familiar with the language.

Answer (score 1):

The [StockWatcher application](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tutorials/1.6/gettingstarted.html) tutorial covers pretty much step by step all you need to play around and get an idea of GWT as a beginner (provided you know a bit of JAVA).

This is part of the [GWT Quick Start](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html) documentation (as mentioned also by someone else) where you can find loads of other examples and resources.

Answer (score 0):

Pick an app that does something similar to what you want, and modify it piece by piece...